# Советы по парсингу файлов без строгого шаблона

Tags: алгоритм, регулярные-выражения, парсер, любой-язык

Есть набор имён файлов, который не имеет чёткого шаблона, но имеет некоторое сходство.

Например:

> One Piece - 757 (CX 1280x720 x264 AAC) [SOFCJ-Raws].mp4 
>   [HorribleSubs] Eromanga-sensei - 01 [1080p].mkv 
>   Shingeki no Kyojin [TV2] - 01 (26) [720p].mkv 
>   Shingeki no Kyojin [TV2] - 02 (27) [720p].mkv 
>  
>   One Piece TV - 741 серия (Shachiburi).mkv

Если человеку реально интуитивно понять что здесь что значит, то вот реально ли как-то программно распарсить подобные разного рода названия? И извлечь из них:

- Название
- Номер сезона, которому соответствует видеофайл
- Номер эпизода, которому соответствует видеофайл

Может есть какие-то готовые библиотеки на подобный случай? 
Наверняка на всё это можно написать просто сложное регулярное выражение, но у меня нет опыта в их написании, а времени на изучение не так много..

Или всё же только в ручную как-то пытаться условными операторами парсить?

Comment: Да, такую задачу лучше решать с помощью готовых решений. Вот библиотека для [Python](https://github.com/divijbindlish/parse-torrent-name/tree/master/PTN). Вот для [JavaScript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/torrent-name-parser).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо за наводку.. к сожалению, автор ориентируется на то, что сезон/эпизод всегда в строгом формате s1e1, в наименовании аниме сериалов такой шаблон вообще не используют. Но всё равно спасибо, может смогу переделать паттерны под свои нужды =/

Comment: Удалось найти решение?

Comment: @FoggyFinder какого-то универсального решения найти не удалось.. я с помощью регулярок извлекаю номер сезона и серии, затем удаляю из строки эти совпадения. Оставшуюся строку очищаю на предмет квадратных скобок вместе с их содержимым. В общем, ничего интересного или эстетически правильного :(